# How to save data in a file swift and load with UserDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

i already got data from JSON API. so i want to save data profile then i load if i want to use it.

this is my code parse json

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
               guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }

                do {
                    //create json object from data
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        print(json)
                        // handle json...



                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(
                            execute:self.LoginDone
                        )
                    }

                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
```

in

> print(json)

i will get data profile like Name, Addres and etc. so, i will save this then load
but i want to save it with another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let create a user object, conform `NSCoding` protocol and implement `decode` and `encode` functions, like this:

```
class User: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name: String!
    var address: String!

    init(name: String, address: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let name = name {
            aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        }
        if let address = address {
            aCoder.encode(address, forKey: "address")
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if aDecoder.containsValue(forKey: "name") {
            self.name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        }
        if aDecoder.containsValue(forKey: "address") {
            self.address = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "address") as! String
        }
    }
}
```

And now, you can save and retrieve a user:

```
let user = User(name: "Danh", address: "1234 XYZ st")

// save user
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: user)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "user")

// retrieve user
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user") as? Data,
    let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? User {
    print("name: \(user.name), address: \(user.address)")
}
```

Comment: where i put the last code ?
so how to passing data from "let json" to class user ??

Comment: You need to extract data (name, address,...) from `let json` and put the last code after this line `// handle json...`

Comment: oh i'm forget. how to load ?

Comment: You can load the saved user `// retrieve user
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user") as? Data,
    let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? User {
    print("name: \(user.name), address: \(user.address)")
}`

Comment: hello sir, sorry i juts try now. because im sick before. in 

"let user = User(name: "Danh", address: "1234 XYZ st")"

how i to set if name and address from json. because from your example you set manual with your name

Comment: let post your JSON, I can help

Comment: i think like this ?

if let profile = json["profile"] as? NSDictionary {

let name = profile["fullName"]
let alamat = profile["homeAddress"]
 let user = User(name: "fullName", address: "homeAddresst")

}

Comment: sir can you tell me how to load data in new file? i try to add your code, nothing happen there.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: when i load nothing happen

Comment: ah, I made a mistake, missing `NSObject`. I updated the answer.

Comment: sir, how about let user = User(name: "Danh", address: "1234 XYZ st"),  i must put it in retrieve too ?

Comment: i want to load data in other class file sir

Comment: just call the block `// save user` when you want to save and `// retrieve user` when you want to load the saved user

Comment: its work gan. but i got output like this name: Optional("Megi"), address: Optional("padanv")

how to delete Optional?

Comment: This is an Optional type, let unwrap it like this: `user.name!`

Comment: haii sir, can i ask again? how to parse data json from .PNG? i want to save and load this link http://web.8villages.com/images/default-avatar.png